# See task progress when using Luigi remotely (with ssh)

Tags: python, ssh, luigi

If using Luigi in a server I am connected to with ssh, is it possible to see the progress of tasks (as I can if I use luigi locally by looking up "localhost" in browser)?

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes

When you run `luigid` "locally", there is a server that starts on your system, which you, as you mentioned, you can access at http://localhost:8082 (or whatever port you specify). To make that work on a remote server, all you need to do is run `luigid` in said server, then point your browser at, instead of http://localhost:8082, http://:8082 (or whatever port you configure `luigid` to listen on.